# PayPal email validation

Tags: php, validation, email, paypal

I am looking for a way to check which of my costumers email addreses are linked to  valid Paypal accounts before i decide to propose this payement method on my website. while searching on google i found this website which does the job perfectly and is 100% accurate 
http://prime-position.ch/cache/9.php
, the only problem is that it is very slow and takes hours with big email lists so my question is how do i find this script in particular or another one that does the same job.

Comment: You don't want to use the emails and their plain text passwords you most likely have to checkout if their PayPal accounts have the same password... do you now? Btw, `shit@gmail.com` verifies in that script... nice PayPal email phishing method ;)

Comment: sorry i didn't really understand what you meant.

Answer (score 2):

**Well... to answer your question... you can't verify an email with PayPal (w/ or w/o API).**

Even with mass payments, they don't give errors, they just notify the recipient to create a PayPal account if they want the money. And the mass payment fails if they don't claim the funds sent to a non-existing PayPal email in 30 days.

***That script is a joke and does not work!** If this was your attempt at phishing for PayPal emails... you need to step up your game :)*

**UPDATE**:
[**AddressVerify API**^](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/AddressVerify_API_Operation_NVP/) is of no use to you. It requires their home address and will not work without it. I don't think you have that... plus your account may get flagged after too many tests.

Comment: are you being seriuos right now i am looking for a way to verify that someone who registered to my website has a valid PayPal account i looked all over the internet and i found a lot of people asking the same thing. I stumbled on this script which i tested with fake and real Paypal adresses and it was pretty acurrate so i came here asking for this script beause i am simply too lazy and noobish to use the Adressverify API

Comment: @raoufsbaghdi To test a fake PayPal email, use a valid domain name. Then see if the script works.

Comment: I tried with 5 valid yahoo email addresses 2 of them were linked to Paypal accounts i had just created and the script worked perfectly

Comment: @raoufsbaghdi Try this one `test@gmail.com` (script says `Checking test@gmail.com ..... Yes`) and keep in mind that `@gmail.com` addresses must have 6+ characters accounts ;) Now stop commenting!